# Need EF/LINQ query to get all tasks assigned to a certain user

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a table called `TPM_TASKS` which contain all tasks, as well as a table called `TPM_USER` which contains all users.  I then have a table called `TPM_USERTASKS` which contains a `UserId` and `TaskId` which stores the assignment of one task to one user.

I'm attempting to select all tasks that are assigned to a given `TPM_USER` entity.  So far, I've tried:

```
TPM_USER user = UserManager.GetUser(context, UserId); //Lookup the user in the DB
var tasks = (from t in context.TPM_TASK.Include("TPM_USER")
             where t.TPM_USER.Contains<TPM_USER>(user)
             select t);
```

However, when I try to iterate into this I get the runtime exception:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Entity.TPM_USER'. Only
>   primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in
>   this context.

I believe it doesn't like me passing in a TPM_USER object into `Contains()`.  This probably makes sense, as it would have to generate a nested SELECT statement rather than an `IN` clause, which perhaps EF isn't capable of doing.  However, surely there's a way to do a query like this, right?

**NOTE:** If you're clever, you're probably about to ask me why I don't just query `TPM_USERTASKS` and then join in the matching `TPM_TASK` instead.  Well, I'd *love* to do this.  However, I've been trying all morning to get EF to generate a TPM_USERTASK model and it simply won't.  The table shows up in the model store, and I can define relationships against it.  It doesn't show up in the list of entities I can add or refresh from the database, and I've even tried deleting the entire .EDMX file and creating it again.  I'm guessing something that gets used in a many-to-many relationship can't also be a stand-alone entity?

Comment: Many-to-many relationships do not generate entities. You can't search by an entire object so you have to compare the primitive field(s) that make up the key. Can you post the TPM_TASK and TPM_USER classes? I'm curious to see why you can't just query the TPM_USER table instead and Include the TPM_TASK table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query would look something like this:

```
var tasks = (from t in context.TPM_TASK.Include("TPM_USER")
            where t.TPM_USER.Any(x => x.Id == user.Id)
            select t);
```

But that's somehow a little bit off anyway. The TPM_USER object should already have a reference to TPM_TASK.
So user.TPM_TASKS should give you all the tasks of the given user, otherwise your model is somehow wrong.

TASKS many-to-many USERS
means:
One Task, many users.
One user, many Tasks.

Or am I wrong?

**Update**:

If you really want to get the TPM_USERTASKS class in your model you'd have to add a separate Key/Id to it.

```
create table TPM_USERTASKS (
    ID      int identity(1,1)   not null
    UserId  int                 not null,
    TaskId  int                 not null,
    constraint [PK_TPM_USERTAKS] primary key (ID)
)
```

Comment: Doh!  Not sure why `user.TPM_TASKS` didn't occur to me.  That works perfectly!  Thanks for the extra explanation though..

Answer (score 2):

Well, you've got to use Navigation properties.

In a many-to-many relation, this means that you must have a

`public virtual ICollection<TPM_USER> TpmUsers {get;set;}`

in your TPM_TASK class

and /or a

`public virtual ICollection<TPM_TASK> TpmTasks{get;set;}`

in you TMP_USER class.

If you don't, you won't be able to write a query joining the two entities.

With that, you can write your query as

```
var userTasks = context.TPM_TASK
                   .Where(task => task.TpmUsers
                         .Any(user => user.Id == UserId));
```